# How to use JQuery "datatable" plugin server side processing with large data in .NET MVC3 razor views

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, razor, datatables

I have a datatable which displays the list of employees. It works fine when I the number of employees in the 0-2000 range but after that there is a serious lag time when loading that page. Which is really not surprizing since it is loading massive amount of data on page load. I looked everywhere and I couldnt find a good example which shows how to do server side processing. The projects that I found on git hub are really not working in my computer(I got a lot of "missing references" errors). This is the code I have working right now

The employees.cshtml

```
@model EmployeeList
@{
    Layout = null;
    ViewBag.Title = "employees";
}
<html>
<head>

<head/>
<body>
      <table id="employees_gridView">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th
                        Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Username
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Job Category
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        Hire Date
                    </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            @if (Model.RowList != null)
            {
                foreach (var item in Model.RowList)
                {


                <tr>
                    <td >
                        @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.DisplayName)
                    </td>
                    <td >
                        @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.UserName)
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.JobCategoryName)
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        @Html.DisplayFor(i => item.hireDate)                          
                    </td>

                </tr>
                }
            }
            </tbody>
            <tfoot>
            </tfoot>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

The datatable jquery looks like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#employees_gridView').dataTable({
            "bDestroy":true,
            "bSortClasses": false,
            "bDeferRender": true,  
            // here is the default setting for number of results to show on a page
            "iDisplayLength": 10,
            "bJQueryUI": true,  
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",

            "aaSorting" :[],
            // here are the column specific settings
            "aoColumns": [
            {"aTargets": [ 0,1 ]},
                         null,
                         {"sClass": "DataTableCenterColumn"},   
                         {"sType":"date", "sClass": "DataTableCenterColumn" 
             }]
        });
});
```

And this is the controller method which processes the page load request

```
public ActionResult Index()
    {
        EmployeeList employeeList = getEmployeeList();
        return View("Index", employeeList );
    }
```

Can someone please show me how I can change this client side datatable to a server side processing datatable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've used JQuery the datatables plugin code before, and even if you get the data quickly (i.e., localhost), it is still slow -- You are spending lots of time in JavaScript/DOM manipulation. To make it fast you must virtualize the JQuery datatable. SO, you actually have to modify both client & server code.

**Step 1**) you need to have a repeatable SQL proc that returns an appropriate subset of rows. Say you have 2000 rows total, you then need a stored proc that is something like

GetEmployeDataRows(@startingrow) -- or pagenumber, or whatever is convenient for you.

Make sure you have a stable query that can be "subsetted" appropriately. This is the key to step 1 which you also want to be fast. Row# or Page# may not be a good choice. If returnng Rows in primary key orded, for example, it may be much smarter to pass your subset parameter as @empnum and the include where EmployeeNumber > @empnum in your GetEmployeDataRows

**Step 2**) Expose a webservice (JSon based usually the best for browser consumption) that takes the startingrow (etc.) as parameter(s)

**Step 3**) -- Virtualize your database based on your json service.

So, this is not a trivial task, but it is the right way to really solve this. There are plenty of examples for each of these steps.

-- followup I should have been clearer, DataTables are slow if you have lots of data, would never recommend using without virtualization if you have a 1000 rows of 20 columns, just too sluggish for me. If you use support old IE it is of course even slower than normal.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. I manged to do it with just step two and three with out making any changes to my DB. Instead of stored procedures i used linq statements. I do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 0):

Here you got an [example](http://datatables.net/usage/server-side) of server side processing trough ajax. 
I dealed with this, but my solution is very complex. If you follow that you are going to make it, pay attention on the json structure that you have to reply from the server.